# Reverse turning of Stepper motor

Tags: programming, motor

I have a stepper motor connected to my Arduino like this using the ULN2003A Darlington Array:

[image: Circuit Diagram]
[image]
(Ignore the potentiometer)

And I have programmed it with the following code:

```
#include <Stepper.h>

int in1Pin = 22;
int in2Pin = 23;
int in3Pin = 24;
int in4Pin = 25;

Stepper motor(512, in1Pin, in2Pin, in3Pin, in4Pin);

void setup()
{
    pinMode(in1Pin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(in2Pin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(in3Pin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(in4Pin, OUTPUT);

    motor.setSpeed(25);
}

void loop()
{
    int steps = 360;

    motor.step(steps);
    delay(500);
}
```

At the moment the motor rotates clockwise, how could I have it so it rotates in the opposite direction?

My code was copied and edited from [here](http://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-arduino-lesson-16-stepper-motors/arduino-code).

---

The problem was that I had the two middle wires the wrong way round as said here: http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?PHPSESSID=kvi8dt2b5en5hhk02dlmjrotl5&topic=143276.msg‌​

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is simple. Just pass a negative number of steps as an argument to `motor.step();`.

Another note: You forgot a semicolon on your second to last line. IIRC this doesn't matter in C, but **it's just bad practice to do this.** If you add a line of code below that, then it won't work.

Example code:

```
#include <Stepper.h>

int in1Pin = 22;
int in2Pin = 23;
int in3Pin = 24;
int in4Pin = 25;

Stepper motor(512, in1Pin, in2Pin, in3Pin, in4Pin);

void setup()
{
    pinMode(in1Pin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(in2Pin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(in3Pin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(in4Pin, OUTPUT);

    motor.setSpeed(25);
}

void loop()
{
    int steps = 360;
    motor.step(steps);
    delay(100);

    steps = -360;
    motor.step(steps);
    delay(500); //Semicolon added
}
```

Comment: Thanks about the semicolon, I was copying out my code in a rush. Also, I've tried a negative number of steps but it doesn't work.

Comment: @user12321 I'm not quite sure. Does it compile? [This page says that a negative number will go the other way.](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/StepperStep) All I can say is to make sure you copied all of the code right. I can't tell what "doesn't work" means.

Comment: Well it compiles and runs but carries on rotating in the same direction

Comment: I found the solution at the here: forum.arduino.cc/index.php?PHPSESSID=kvi8dt2b5en5hhk02dlmjrotl5&topic=143276.msg109779#msg109779. I had the wires the wrong way round.

Comment: @user Does the negative work then?

Comment: Yeah, it works like a dream!